# Is there a JavaFX "Style Guide" for applications?

Tags: guidelines, human-interface-guideline, style-guide

I was hoping to find a style guide, for JavaFX applications.  Something like you can find for:

- [Android](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html)
- [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/)
- [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa511258.aspx)
- and even [Motif](http://www.s-and-b.ru/syshlp/motif_guide/MotifStyleGuide/TOC.html)

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: I'm still new here but this question seems like it might get flagged as "not a ux question" but did you find this document yet?  --  http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: Yes, thanks @AlbertLang, I've seen that.  That guide is more of a reference to support "styling" your UI, I was thinking more of a guide advocating consistent/usable UI design rules.

Comment: You can use [Jfoenix library ](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix)  and follow [Materiel Design guide line] (https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette)

Answer (score 1):

This guide may be what you are looking for although it isn't specifically to JavaFX it does try and explain Java user interface components across a broad spectrum of Java based frameworks.

### [Java Look and Feel Design Guidelines](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-136139.html)

There is also a nice list of Human Interface Guidelines kept up to date on wikipedia.

[Human interface guidelines - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_guidelines)

Hope this helps